# Move SubView of ChildViewController using scrollViewDidScroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I am using a `viewController` to handle two `ChildViewController`s, each containing a `UITableView`. Would it be possible to set the the position y of a SubView of `viewController` (e.g. a `UILabel`) depending on the `scrollView.contentOffset` of the current `ChildViewController`?

It works fine with its own subviews already,..

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        self.testConstt.constant = scrollView.contentOffset.y

    }
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just observe the correct scroll view using a conditional statement. I assume the scroll views of the children are table views, so you may do something like this:

```
let tableViewA = UITableView(...)
let tableViewB = UITableView(...)
let someScrollView = UIScrollView()

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView == tableViewA {
        // observe a specific table view's scroll view and do something
    } else if scrollView == someScrollView {
        // observe a specific scroll view and do something
    }
}
```

Remember, `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView` so they can be treated the same in `scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView:)`.

Comment: I keep getting this error: 'Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value' as soon as the func gets called. even if it's the right tableView,..do you have any other ideas? :)

Comment: Which property is optional?

Comment: The constraints I've added via main.storyboard: @IBOutlet weak var constraintTop: NSLayoutConstraint! Thanks man!

Comment: I don't user interface builder, I think it's a pile of junk, so I'm not much help there, sorry!